# Horizontal Projection From The Top Of An Inclined Plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, projectile

A ball is projected horizontally with a speed $v$ from the top of a plane inclined at an angle of 45 degrees with the horizontal. How far from the point of projection will the ball strike the plane?

My attempt at a solution:

I used the range formula for an inclined plane and I got the answer as $\sqrt{2} v^2/g$, which isn't the right answer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Seconding @JohnRennie - if you show us some of your working we can help you with a specific problem. But we won't do the whole question for you!

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal component of velocity is constant (assumed), so $x=v\,t$
From acceleration due to gravity, $y=\frac{1}{2}\,g\,t^2$

The ball hits the plane when $x=y$ so set them equal to each other and solve for $t\,
vt=\frac{1}{2}\,g\,t^2$: we get $v=\frac{1}{2}\,g\,t$ and $t=2\,\frac{v}{g}$.

At this time $t$, $x$ is equal to $y$.

To get the horizontal distance, plug in to the first equation:

$$x = v\times\left(2\,\frac{v}{g}\right)$$

so that $x = 2 v^2/g$

That is all

Comment: Please use Latex for this site. Have a look at my edits to get you underway.